# What does `select` the same table as `from` mean?

Tags: postgresql

Given a table

```
mytestdb=# select * from foo;
 id | name 
----+------
  4 | Tim
(1 row)
```

what does `select foo from foo` output, i.e. what does `select` the same table as `from` mean? Thanks.

```
mytestdb=# select foo from foo;
   foo   
---------
 (4,Tim)
(1 row)
```

Thanks.

My question comes from understanding what is the input to `json_agg()` in

```
mytestdb=# select json_agg(foo) from foo;
        json_agg         
-------------------------
 [{"id":4,"name":"Tim"}]
(1 row)
```

See http://johnatten.com/2015/04/22/use-postgres-json-type-and-aggregate-functions-to-map-relational-data-to-json/

Comment: As unlikely as it seems, the code you stumbled across must work with a table that has a column with the same name as the table.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: It was *well* hidden in the docs.

Answer (score 4):

Using a table name or alias in a select list [generates](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-USAGE) a [composite value](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html) of the table's current row. Passing the table name or alias to a function that can accept a composite value will invoke the function for each row.

Comment: That is very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

The construct

```
SELECT foo FROM foo;
```

is called a *whole-row reference* in PostgreSQL, since it retrieves the whole row as one.

Things become clearer if you know that with every `CREATE TABLE` goes an implicit `CREATE TYPE` that defines a composite type of the same name as the table.

You can easily see that by querying the catalogs:

```
SELECT typname, typtype, typinput, typoutput
FROM pg_type
WHERE typname = 'text';
```

So the result of the query above is a single item of type `foo`. Since it is a composite type, it is represented in row notation: surrounded by parentheses and the attribute values separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

(this is a repost from an [another answer](https://another%20answer), to a closed question, for visibility)

Postgresql treats table in `select table` as a composite value. You can think of it as a type that has many fields (table columns), from the docs:

> In PostgreSQL, a reference to a table name (or alias) in a query is effectively a reference to the composite value of the table's current row. For example, if we had a table inventory_item as shown above, we could write:

```
SELECT c FROM inventory_item c;
```

> This query produces a single composite-valued column, so we might get output like:

```
           c
------------------------
 ("fuzzy dice",42,1.99)
(1 row)
```

source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-USAGE