# What is `Publisher()` in `Publisher(pub_name, pub_branch)`?

Tags: sql, postgresql, object-relational-model

From Database System Concepts, for SQL commands for object-relational databases:

```
create type Publisher as
(name varchar(20),
branch varchar(20));

create type Book as
(title varchar(20),
author array varchar(20) array [10],
pub date date,
publisher Publisher,
keyword set varchar(20) multiset);

insert into books
values (’Compilers’, array[’Smith’, ’Jones’],
new Publisher(’McGraw-Hill’, ’New York’),
multiset[’parsing’, ’analysis’]);

create table flat_Book as
(title varchar(20),
author array varchar(20) array [10],
pub_name varchar(20),
pub_branch varchar(20));

select title, author, Publisher(pub_name, pub_branch) as publisher
from ﬂat_books
group by title, author, publisher;
```

What is `Publisher(pub_name, pub_branch)` and `Publisher()` in  it?

`Publisher()` doesn't seem to be the constructor method of `Publisher` type, because a call on a constructor method needs `new`, e.g. `new Publisher(’McGraw-Hill’, ’New York’)`.

I guess PostgreSQL may have similar commands, since it follows SQL standard well and is also object-relational DBMS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As [Laurenz Albe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51416686/479863) mentioned in his answer to yesterday's similar question, `create table T` does an implicit `create type T` behind the scenes to create a composite type with the same structure as the table.

Then we look at [type casts in the fine manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS):

> A type cast specifies a conversion from one data type to another. PostgreSQL
>   accepts two equivalent syntaxes for type casts:
>
> ```
> CAST ( expression AS type )
> expression::type
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> It is also possible to specify a type cast using a function-like syntax:
>
> ```
> typename ( expression )
> ```

And:

> **Note**
>
> The function-like syntax is in fact just a function call. When one of the two standard cast syntaxes is used to do a run-time conversion, it will internally invoke a registered function to perform the conversion. By convention, these conversion functions have the same name as their output type, and thus the “function-like syntax” is nothing more than a direct invocation of the underlying conversion function.

Putting that together:

- `create table publisher` also does a `create type publisher`.
- For a given type `T`, `T(expr)` is a type cast.
- So `publisher(a, b)` is essentially a type cast using the underlying type casting function.

Reviewing the [Composite Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html) section of the documentation would also be helpful.